# Google spreadsheet: Add days to date set by inputBox, fill range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I fill up a range in a Google Spreadsheet based on a startDate that has been set by an inputBox? Basically, (1) User inputs startDate; (2) script fills up cells A1 to A13 starting from startDate and adding 7 days for each row.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
var startDate = Browser.inputBox('What is the start date?', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
for (var k = 0; k < (13); k++) {
  sheet.getRange((k+1),1).setValue(startDate + k * 7);
}
```

Unfortunately I think setValue treats startDate as a string? So for an input of 15/10/2013 in the box, and cells formatted to dd-mmm-yyyy, the cells are filled up with 15-Oct-20130, 15-Oct-20137, 15-Oct-201314 and so on. What I'd hoped for was 15-Oct-2013, 22-Oct-2013, 29-Oct-2013 and so on. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of UIApp's dedicated widget to choose the starting date and of using spreadsheet formulas to create your date sequence (as you know that `=date+7` in spreadsheet gives automatically the date 7 days later.

Here is how it could go :

```
function dateSequence() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Choose a start Date').setHeight('100').setWidth('200');
  var date = app.createDateBox().setName('date').setValue(new Date());
  var clickHandler = app.createServerHandler('setDate').addCallbackElement(date);
  app.add(date).add(app.createButton('submit', clickHandler));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app)
}

function setDate(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication().close();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(e.parameter.date);
  for (var k = 1; k < 13; k++) {
    sheet.getRange((k+1),1).setFormula("= (A"+k+")+"+7);
  }
  return app;
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks! Using setFormula() was a good tip. I wanted value-only content in the cells, though, so what I ended up doing was (1) using setFormula() to fill up the cells with the right dates; then (2) running a getValues() followed by a setValues() for the same range to replace the formulae with values. Oh, and I didn't bother wtih UiApp, just used the original Browser.inputBox . Kinda brute force, but Solved.

Comment: As you want... might be dangerous to use Browser input if someone else has to fill in the correct date format but it's up to you...:-)  please consider accepting the answer nevertheless.